# Review code of system views

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there any possibility to get into system view code, just to realize how view was constructed, which object it uses, and so on...

I don't need do change them, just to view code.

Comment: Try [`sp_helptext 'YourViewName'`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176112.aspx?ppud=4)

Comment: Not so nice, but can be helpful

Comment: if you want to get result in text instead of rows pres 'ctrl + t' in your ssms

Comment: Another option is also to use SSMS/SSMSE and click the `Generate Script` button on the toolbar before you save.  Alternatively try right-clicking the object and `Script <object> As` -> `CREATE TO`.

Comment: When use `Generate Script` option, there is no system objects, only user defined. Also, You cannot just right click on system view and choose `SCRIPT <object> AS ` because that option isn't available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use:

```
select object_definition(object_id('ViewName'))
```

It gives you the definition on one line, unlike using `SP_HelpText` which gives you the definition split into chunks - often splitting mid word, which is very unhelpful.

Works on system objects too, and for a variety of types (not just views):

- Check constraint
- Default (constraint or stand-alone)
- SQL stored procedure
- SQL scalar function
- Rule
- Replication filter procedure
- SQL trigger (schema-scoped DML trigger, or DDL trigger at either the database or server scope)
- SQL inline table-valued function
- SQL table-valued function
- View

[MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms176090.aspx).